# Event assignment vs .live()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, live

Time ago, I used to use this solution:

```
$('<div class="ok" />')
.appendTo('body');

$('div.ok')
.live('click',function(){ alert(); })
```

Now I use this one:

```
$('<div class="ok" />')
.appendTo('body')
.click(function(){ alert(); })
```

How is performance difference? I believe the second solution is better because It doesn't require a live() .
Is it always this way (also with many elements) or not? why?

Comment: You also know that `.live()` is deprecated, right?

Comment: Yes I know. We can assume to use .on()

Comment: @user1392191: If any of the provided responses have answered your question mark one of them as accept. However, if you still have issues with this question let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is performance difference?

Well, when you used to use `live`. `live` always bound to the `document` and preventing events from bubbling up was impossible too as the event was triggered after it already bubbled all the way through.

In that sense `live()` was not very performance friendly.

Your second code sample binds to the object directly as it is created, making it perform better and more flexible when compared to `live()`. You can now event prevent the event from bubbling up and so on.

Binding the event at creation to the element directly compared to using `on()`, specifying the closest static element to bind to has only a very small performance benefit.

```
// Performs slightly better than on() but cannot be executed from anywhere unless the element is added at the same time.
$('<div class="ok" />').appendTo('body').click(function(){ alert(); })
```

The benefit is smaller though than the benefit of being able to bind your event handlers before the element is added in a common method for example.

The below does the same as your second code sample but can be nicely executed within a common method and does not have to be part of adding the dynamic element.

```
// Can be called in a common init method for example and still work.
$(body).on('click', '.ok', function(){ alert();})
```

`on()` has the great benefit that you can separate the adding of elements from the binding of events.

Answer (score 0):

The second method would offer a negligible performance boost more than likely (assuming you don't have a wild amount of `div.ok` elements dropping into the DOM), since the DOM doesn't need to be searched for again. Another option would be to use the `html/props` signature instead:

```
$("<div>", { 
    'class': "ok",
    'click': function () {
        alert("You clicked the new element!");
    } 
}).appendTo("body");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w4Tj3/

Keep in mind that `.live()` is deprecated. If you're going to use event delegation, it's best to use `.on()` from here on out. However, in your case, you don't necessarily need either. Instead, to mimic `.live()` you'd set up a listener on the `document`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ok", function () {
    alert("You clicked an .ok element!");
});
```

The way this works is by leveraging the bubbling behavior of events. When you click an element, the click traverses up the DOM until it finally reaches the `document` object. jQuery then checks to see if the element that initiated the click matches our selector (`.ok`) and if it does it runs the anonymous function.

To see better performance, don't bind to `document`, but rather to something much closer to your dynamically-added elements. For instance, if you're dynamically adding `li` elements, bind to their parent `ol` or `ul`. This way, the event doesn't need to propagate far before it's handled.

With event delegation in place, you could remove the `click` logic from the dynamically-added `div` itself:

```
$("<div>", {'class': 'ok'}).appendTo("body");
```